# Merge records in one

Tags: python, sql, perl, parsing, unix

I have a file with a lot of records of the type:

```
|1|a|b|c|||||||
|1||||aa|bb|cc||||
|1|||||||aaa|bbb|ccc|
|2|fd|ef|gf|||||||
|1||||zz|yy|dd||||
```

I need to merge the records with the same value in the first field so that ideally it would look like this (assuming the last record is the newest one):

```
|1|a|b|c|zz|yy|dd|aaa|bbb|ccc|
|2|fd|ef|gf|||||||
```

I've been thinking about the best way to do this. I've considered putting everything in a database table using the first field as a primary key, I've also been looking into hashes with perl... But nothing sounds ideal. Thoughts? Something in perl or python would be great but I'm open to almost anything I can run on unix.

Thanks!

Comment: Both sound like reasonable approaches... What have you tried?

Comment: |1||||aa|bb|cc|||| this is missing in the result. Which one is newest?

Comment: @NizamMohamed it's missing because it would ideally be overwritten by the latest record with the zz|yy|dd

Comment: @AKHolland I've just been writing down data structures in a piece of paper and doing small test cases, but I keep feeling like there's some better (great even!) way of doing it that I can't think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my %merged_rows;
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my @fields = split(/\|/, $_, -1);
   my $id = $fields[1];
   my $merged_row = $merged_rows{$id} ||= [];

   $merged_row->[$_] = $fields[$_]
      for grep { length($fields[$_]) || $_ > $#$merged_row } 0..$#fields;
}

for my $id ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys(%merged_rows) ) {
   print(join('|', @{ $merged_rows{$id} }), "\n");
}
```

If the keys are all small numbers, you can get a small speed boost by using an array instead of a hash to hold the merged rows.

---

- When there's no limit, `split` removes empty trailing fields, so `|1|a|b|c|||||||` would be the same as `|1|a|b|c`.
- `$z = $x ||= $y;` is the same thing as `$x ||= $y; $z = $x;`
- `$x ||= $y;` is basically the same as `$x = $x || $y;`;  It assigns the RHS to the LHS if the LHS is false. In context, it does `$merged_rows{$id} = [];` if it's the first time we've encountered `$id`.
- `[]` creates an empty array and returns a reference to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One more question... what does this do? my $merged_row = $merged_rows{$id} ||= []; 

Oh, and is there any difference between using -1 as a LIMIT in split and not using any limit? Thanks!

Comment: The answers to your comment have been added to the Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script in python that will do it.

It will overwrite only if the section is not empty in the order the lines came in.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def merge_lines():
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
        with open('output.txt', 'w') as file_out:
            output_dict = defaultdict(list)
            for line in file:
                split_line = line.split('|')
                # Remove first empty string
                del split_line[0]
                # If we havn't seen this record before then add it to dictionary
                if split_line[0] not in output_dict:
                    output_dict[split_line[0]] = split_line
                else:
                    # If we have seen it then update the sections providing 
                    # they are not emptystring ('')
                    for index, val in enumerate(split_line):
                        if val != '':
                            output_dict[split_line[0]][index] = val

            # Join sections back together and write lines to file
            for line_values in output_dict.values():
                file_out.write('|' + '|'.join(line_values))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    merge_lines()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def update_col(l1,l2):
    for i,v in enumerate(l2):
        if not v:
            continue
        l1[i] = v

out = []
for l in open('rec.txt'):
    l = l.strip().split('|')
    for r in out:
            if r[1] == l[1]:
                    update_col(r,l)
                    break
    else:   
            out.append(l)

for l in out:
    print '|'.join(l)
```

Output
`|1|a|b|c|zz|yy|dd|aaa|bbb|ccc|
|2|fd|ef|gf|||||||`